# Pod does not start with status CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I used to have the following configuration where we used to have the single url. With this configuration we were able to start the pod without any issues.

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: DaemonSet
    metadata:
      name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      annotations:
        reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          some-service: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      template: #required fields
        spec:
          hostNetwork: yes
          containers:
           - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
             image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
             imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
             env:
             - name: HOST_URL
               valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: some-config
                  key: some-url
```

Now we have multiple urls hence we have changed the yaml to use initContainer to get the valid url then set it the env as shown below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      some-service: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  template: #required fields
    spec:
      hostNetwork: yes
      containers:
       - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
         image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
         imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
         command:
         - sh
         - -c
         - env HOST_URL=$(cat /tmp/ip.env)
         volumeMounts:
         - name: workdir
           mountPath: /tmp
      initContainers:
       - name: wait-for-url
         image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
         volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/tmp"
            name: workdir
         env:
          - name: multipleUrls
            valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
               name: some-config
               key: multipleUrls
         command: 
           - '/bin/bash'
           - '-c'
           - |
             
             echo "Actual Data: $multipleUrls"
             :
             :
             Logic to find the valid url and store it in the /tmp/ip.env file
             :
             :
             echo "Accessible Url is:$hosturl"
             echo $hosturl> /tmp/ip.env
             
             if [ -s /tmp/ip.env ]; then 
                echo "HOSTURL is: " `cat /tmp/ip.env` 
                exit 0;
             else 
                sleep 10 
                exit 1;
             fi
      volumes:
       - name: workdir
         emptyDir: {}
```

We see that initContainer is execute successfully without any error. But we see that Pod is not getting started.

## kubectl pod describe pod-name

```
    Name:         some-name-nckfs
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         10.22.44.169/10.22.44.169
Start Time:   Sat, 29 Oct 2022 15:11:11 +0000
Labels:       controller-revision-hash=55ff545b89
              pod-template-generation=32
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.22.44.169
IPs:
  IP:           10.22.44.169
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/some-something
Init Containers:
  wait-for-hosturl:
    Container ID:  docker://62e3b20b6eeeca4f37e78c02fa8d68b482bde1644fc30a0ed94f788c35d3cd86
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:805f01431e534713510826a63dab75873d45aa96c6a9614f2c9bfbeab800a774
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/bash
      -c

      ::
      ::

    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 29 Oct 2022 15:11:12 +0000
      Finished:     Sat, 29 Oct 2022 15:11:12 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      multipleUrls:  <set to the key 'multipleUrls' of config map 'some-config'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /tmp from workdir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-vks68 (ro)
Containers:
  some-something:
    Container ID:  docker://1fd6d60a70a6e2c10339809e4bb3084738aee7500dc0087973801c1c3a5a497a
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:805f01431e534713510826a63dab75873d45aa96c6a9614f2c9bfbeab800a774
    Port:          9091/TCP
    Host Port:     9091/TCP
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      env HOST_URL=$(cat /tmp/ip.env)
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 29 Oct 2022 15:57:42 +0000
      Finished:     Sat, 29 Oct 2022 15:57:42 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  14
    Environment:
    Mounts:
      /tmp from workdir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-vks68 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  workdir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  default-token-vks68:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-vks68
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Created    49m                    kubelet            Created container wait-for-hosturl
  Normal   Started    49m                    kubelet            Started container wait-for-hosturl
  Normal   Created    48m (x5 over 49m)      kubelet            Created container some-something
  Normal   Started    48m (x5 over 49m)      kubelet            Started container some-something
  Warning  BackOff    4m57s (x212 over 49m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

## kubectl podname logs:

```
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.43.0.1:443
HOSTNAME=something
HOME=/root
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.43.0.1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.43.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.43.0.1
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
PWD=/
HOST_URL=10.22.44.168
```

Comment: Did @SYN solution help you to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

From the description you're showing us, it looks like your main container runs one command then exits:

```
Containers:
  some-something:
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      env HOST_URL=$(cat /tmp/ip.env)
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 29 Oct 2022 15:57:42 +0000
```

This tells us that container did exit with code 0.

While the command looks just wrong. It won't change your environment for one. And for sure it would exit right away.

Command should start a long-running process, if you want to get it rid of those CrashLoopBackOff.

Should use a Job instead of a Deployment, if you mean to run a one-off command that is expected to exit.

Should look at `kubectl logs -p`, assuming you're somehow not sharing the exact configuration, and that there is some command expected to start, instead of that env HOST_URL thing.

---

And I should have looked at the initContainer closer, to realize that there's an easy way to do what you're trying to do. You're using hostNetwork, so your Pod IP is actually your Node IP.

If you want to get your Pod IP, as an environment variable, you would do:

```
[daemonset / deployment / ...]
spec:
  template:
    containers:
    - env:
      - name: HOST_IP
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: status.podIP
```

Remove the commands / args override from your Pod. The default entrypoint from your container would then be used. Maybe you won't have those crashLoopBackOff, then. Or if you do: check back on pods logs (`kubectl logs -n <ns> -p <pod>`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. As I'm new to this stuff can we somehow set the environment variable for the main container from the initcontainer itself so that we can't use the command in the main container.

Comment: Or can we set the config map value from the initcontainer so that i can refer that in the main container

Comment: ah, well, you should be able to have it working if you fixed the command (should probably be `HOST_IP=$(cat file)`, removing the `env` part), AND adding another command afterwards, that would run whichever command we are overriding / default image entrypoint. However, if you want to get the Pod IP (which, in case of hostNetwork, will match your node IP), we can use a fieldRef setting this ... I'll add a sample to my initial answer ...

Comment: No I don't want the Pod IP. We will be getting multiple IPs from the config Map Ofcourse it's not the Pod IP) we will see do processing where we will check which one is accessible from this POD then use it for the business logic)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear before. We used to have single external audit server before which used to go offline hence we have a multiple audit servers now. Thays what multiple urls contains.. now in the init container we will see which one is accessible from the pod (i.e ping the list of available IPs and return which one is accessible) now main container need this accessible ip and do its own logic

Comment: Your initContainer doesn't yet do what you mentioned here:  from what I can see, you have that multipleurl environment var set from a configmap. And the hosturl one: either it's already in your image, or that variable is just empty. 1/ somewhere in initcontainer, hosturl should be initialized. 2/ writing it for re-use by another container: you should use an EmptyDir. A ConfigMap-based volume is read only, by default. 3/ Then you do need to override commands for your application container WHILE PRESERVING original entrypoint. Or add "sleep 86400", avoiding crashloops